# SSRS report dynamic values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a row group in my table.
My calculation should pick the value based on the value returned from group for that specific row.That means, the report expressions associated with different columns should be based on the current value returned from the row group.

Eg: (report with two columns)
Col1--Category (row Group and detail)
Col2--Amount (Sum of amount based on category)

Now the sum expression is written in amount column on the Category group like
If Category.value= then sum(amount)
How can I use /get the dynamic value to drive the sum in expression .Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Adding the missed portion in the question
Category.value= <Dynamic column from DB>

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is to me. Please post sample data from your dataset along with your report design and expressions.